# What is the shortest distance from the origin to the intersection of $xyz=a$ and $y=bx$?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Constraints: $a,b>0$

Here is what I have so far:

In order to get the shortest distance from the origin, we set $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ subject to the constrains $xyz=a$ and $y=bx$. By Lagrange multipliers, let $g(x,y,z,t,s)=x^2+y^2+z^2+t(xyz-a)+s(y-bx)$. We can solve

\begin{cases} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=2x+tyz-bs=0 \\ \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=2y+txz+s=0 \\ \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}=2z+txy=0 \\ \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}=xyz-a=0 \\ \frac{\partial g}{\partial s}=y-bx=0, \end{cases}

and get the relation

\begin{cases} x^6=\frac{2a^2}{b^2(1+b^2)} \\ y=bx \\ z=\frac{a}{bx^2}. \end{cases}

Therefore, the shortest distance is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

However, when I plug into the expression above, I get [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+sqrt%28%28%282a%5E2%29%2F%28b%5E2+%281%2Bb%5E2%29%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29%2B+b%5E2%2a%28%282a%5E2%29%2F%28b%5E2+%281%2Bb%5E2%29%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29+%2B+%28a%5E2+%2F+b%5E2%29%2a%28%282a%5E2%29%2F%28b%5E2+%281%2Bb%5E2%29%29%29%5E%28-1%2F3%29%29) very long expression. According to the textbook the answer should be $3\sqrt{\frac{a(1+b^2)}{2b}}$. Is it just a LOT of algebra that I need to do to get to the previous expression, or have I erred somewhere or is the textbook wrong (the textbook is known to have many errors)?

Comment: Please explain how you got $x^6=\frac{2a^2}{b^2(1+b^2)}$.

Comment: @vadim123 I used Maple, a computer algebra system. Wolfram Alpha should also be able to produce it.

Comment: @vadim123 [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2x+%2B+t+y+z+-+bs+%3D+0+and+2y+%2B+t+x+z+%2B+s+%3D+0+and+2z+%2B+t+x+y+%3D0+and+x+y+z+-+a+%3D+0+and+y+-+b+x+%3D+0) shows that result transiently, then it changes to something else (not sure why).

Answer (score 0):

From $y=bx$ you get $x^2+y^2+z^2=x^2(1+b^2)+z^2$ and $xyz=a\iff xbxz=a\iff x^2=\frac{a}{bz}$, hence determine the extrema of $\frac{a}{b
z}(1+b^2)+z^2$.